# How to use an if/while loop together in Python?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, addition

So basically I want to do this generate a random number (this I know how to do) if that number is even (or `number%2 == 0`) then divide it by 2 then if the resulting number is odd (or `number%2 > 0`) then multiply by 3 and add 1. If that didn't make much sense here is an exmaple

- Pick a number like 26 (this is even so divide by 2)
- Resulting number is 13 (this is odd so multiply by 3 add 1)
- Resulting number is 40 (this is even so divide by 2)

Continue this process until the number is == 1

I am not sure what loop to use to do this so any help is very appreciated! :)

Comment: And what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: You might want to either look into `while True`, or perhaps research a bit of recursion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve my code for euler 14?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078987/how-can-i-improve-my-code-for-euler-14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
number = # generate random number
while number != 1:
    if number % 2: # if number is odd, multiply by 3, add 1
        number *= 3
        number += 1
    else: # if number is even, divide by 2
        number /= 2
```

You can run a bit of cheeky code to keep track of iterations, if you like:

```
num_iterations = 0
number = # generate random number
while number != 1:
    num_iterations += 1
    if number % 2:
        number = number * 3 + 1
    else:
        number /= 2
```

Comment: Thanks so mucH! But just one question- On line 3 where it says "if number % 2" how does this clarify the number is odd wouldnt have to be something along the lines of "if number % 2 > 0" ???

Comment: It basically checks if there is a remainder when the number is divided by 2. If the number is even, that number is 0, which would evaluate as false. If the number is odd, it will be 1, which would evaluate as true.

Comment: @user3528395 `number % 2` returns the modulus of your number and `2`. If the number divides evenly, it returns zero (and `if 0` doesn't execute). Any other result evaluates to `True` (`if 1` executes). Note also that `> 0` is unnecessary in all cases, since `x % 2` CAN ONLY BE either `0` or `1`, it can never be `> 1` or `< 0`. Always test explicitly if you need to test at all.

Comment: Ok one more question is there anyway to print the steps it takes to get the code back to one. This would allow me to run maybe just one very big number then print the results and steps so if any number prints within there you know it is included in the numbers that follow this /2 and *3+1 pattern rule.

Comment: @user3528395 sure it's definitely possible. I'd look into putting print statements inside your `while` loop that spits back the number and whatever you're doing to it. I'll leave that for you to implement though. Maybe something like `"{} is odd so * 3 + 1".format(number)`

Comment: Ok thanks! So do if statements only use print or can it use print and return within it?

Comment: @user3528395 `print` will output a string to `stdout` (usually to your console unless you've redefined it). `return` will pass control back to the calling scope and assign value to the function (`multiply_by_two(number)` should `return number*2`, for instance. It wouldn't make sense to `print` that number). `print` and `return` really have little to do with one another.

Comment: Thanks so much sorry for all the noob questions haha but is there anyway to get it to print not onto the console but into a list like: steps = [ numbers print here]?

Comment: @user3528395 if you were going to do that, I would initialize a `list` before your loop and in each branch of the `if` block do `listname.append(number)` then `return` that list at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know how many steps would it take to get the `number` equal to one, i.e. the number of iterations is unknown , use a `while` loop:

```
number = # random number

while number != 1:
    if number % 2:
        number *= 3
        number += 1
    else:
        number /= 2
```

Or another approach:

```
number = # random number

while True:
    if number == 1:
        break
    elif number % 2:  # odd
        number *= 3
        number += 1
    else:          # even
        number /= 2
```